# Java, массив и двойной цикл for

Tags: java, массивы, циклы

Есть массив, нужно каждый элемент массива прогнать через цикл с добавлением цифр. Проблема в том, что код прогоняет только первый элемент массива. Попытался изменить цикл `for-each` на `for`, но результат тот же.

```
for (String s : array) {
    for (int i = 97; calendar.compareTo(calendarNow) < 0; i++) {
        if (i % 100 == 0) 
            i = 0;
        if (i < 10) 
            System.out.println(s + " 0" + i);
        else 
            System.out.println(s + " " + i);
        calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Чем заполнен массив? И какие вообще цели программы?

Comment: Цифрами в формате String. Задание: Создать и распечатать массив серий паспортов граждан РФ

Comment: Как создать? По какому алгоритму?

Comment: По выше представленному. Нужно прокрутить во втором цикле for все элементы массива.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

нужно для каждого элемента массива создавать новую переменную `calendar`:

```
for (String s : array) {
    for (int i = 97, Calendar calendar = newCalendar();
         calendar.compareTo(calendarNow) < 0; i++) {
        if (i % 100 == 0) 
            i = 0;
        if (i < 10) 
            System.out.println(s + " 0" + i);
        else 
            System.out.println(s + " " + i);
        calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
    }
}
```

где `newCalendar()` возвращает новый объект календаря, установленный на заданную дату.

Comment: Не работает ИСР всё выделяет красным. "cannot resolve symbol/cannot resolve method".

Comment: Метод надо самому писать.

Answer (score 0):

Ответом оказалось поместить `calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1997);` перед вторым циклом for. Вот так:

```
for (String s : array) {
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1997);
    for (int i = 97; calendar.compareTo(calendarNow) < 0; i++) {
        ...
```